# material-moment-adapter" has missing dependencies

Tags: angular, angular-material

Anyone has a clue on how to solve this one?

```
Error: The target entry-point "@angular/material-moment-adapter" has missing dependencies:
 - @angular/core
 - @angular/material/core
```

npm -v 7.24.1

I deleted the node_modules folder, updated npm and ran npm install once again with same results

Comment: Could You provide more information?
Which Angular version do You use, when exactly the Error happens, the package.json file or detailed explanation on how to reproduce the error?

Comment: the problem appeared after installing "@angular/material-moment-adapter"
"dependencies": { 
   "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",

Comment: I was adding MomentDateAdapter to the imports section :|

Answer (score 0):

Try to install missing dependencies :

```
    npm install @angular/core @angular/material/core
```

Comment: @angular/core is the "core" component of the angular framework and it is installed by default when creating an angular app using angular cli